# Billing cycle in strip subscription on every 1st of month

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-customer-portal

I am creating stripe subscription and selecting Start billing cycle on

1st of every month, now even the 1st date already passed but on stripe subscription it is still showing as Next invoice on 1 Nov and i am not able to add usage record as it throws error
`Cannot create the usage record with this timestamp because timestamps must be before the subscription's current period end time.`

[image]

Comment: When are you trying to add the usage records for? That error message implies that the call will work if you create a usage record that is within the subscription's current billing cycle (you can check when this is via the subscription's `current_period_start` and `current_period_end` properties)
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_start
https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-current_period_end

Comment: Subscription billing cycle is on 1st of every month, and 1st date of november is already passed and on stripe it is still showing Next invoice on 1 Nov. I think it should show 1 December.